# Python match all URL's in a file and list each on new line in file

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to get a script that opens a file, matches the file for all URL's and outputs a new file with just the matches.
What currently happens with the below is just get the first match. The file I'm parsing is basically 1 line with multiple urls
"This is a a random string of urls http://www.yandex.ru:8080, http://www.hao123.com:8080, another bit here , [http://www.wordpress.com:8080,"](http://www.wordpress.com:8080,%22)

```
import re

with open("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.txt") as f:
    Lines = f.readlines()
file_to_write = open("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\output.txt", "w")
pattern = 'https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))'
matches = []
for line in Lines:
   m = re.search(pattern, line)
   if m:
     matches.append(m.group(0))
   print(matches)
   file_to_write.write("\n".join(matches))
```

Now, if I replace the regex with something more simple like "'(https?://.*):(\d*)'" I get all the matches but they are not separated on the lines, they are all joined together on one line.

Not sure how to quite modify the script OR the Regex to capture ALL urls' base:port and add to a new line.

Current output with Regex ('(https?://.*):(\d*)'):

```
http://www.yandex.ru:8080, http://www.hao123.com:8080, antoher bit here , http://www.wordpress.com:8080,http://www.gmw.cn:8080, http://www.tumblr.com:8080/test/etete/eete, http://www.paypal.com:8080
```

Desired Output:

```
http://www.yandex.ru:8080
http://www.hao123.com:8080
http://www.wordpress.com:8080
http://www.gmw.cn:8080
http://www.tumblr.com:8080
http://www.paypal.com:8080
```

Comment: You may capture the port in your regex - `(?::(\d+))?` - and add the port match `if m.group(1)`.

Comment: Not sure I follow? I'm already capturing the url and port. But instead of 1 line output, i want all URL's on a new line

Comment: In the file you write to, they are all on different lines, you use `"\n".join()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with the following:

```
for line in Lines:
   m = re.findall(pattern, line)
   if m:
     print('\n'.join(m))
     matches += m
file_to_write.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

That seems to do what i need.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `re.findall` (and the pattern you have):

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = 'This is a a random string of urls http://www.yandex.ru:8080, http://www.hao123.com:8080, another bit here, http://www.wordpress.com:8080,'
>>> pattern = 'https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))'
>>> urls = re.findall(pattern, s)
>>> urls
['http://www.yandex.ru:8080', 'http://www.hao123.com:8080', 'http://www.wordpress.com:8080']
```

You can then use the `list` named `urls` as you see fit. For example, to write the URLs in a file, you can use (as you already have) `file_to_write.write('\n'.join(urls))`. For illustration:

```py
>>> print('\n'.join(urls))
http://www.yandex.ru:8080
http://www.hao123.com:8080
http://www.wordpress.com:8080
```

Comment: This works, but it assumes that all the matches will be on one line. I had made it a list to use the .append to capture URL's that won't all be on the same line.  if that makes sense.

Comment: Yep, in your description you have "The file I'm parsing is basically 1 line with multiple urls". I interpreted this as the "input file has one line", and if this is the case abstracting how you read this one line to `s`, my answer is accurate. If by that you meant that your input file has many lines and each has multiple URLs, then indeed the way to go is a you say, i.e., initialize an empty `list`, loop over the lines, and append to the list the results of applying `re.find` to each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your first (not simplified) regex works well with the given urls.
The problem is you are picking only the first match in the line
due to `re.search()`.

On the other hand, your simplified regex (I assume it will be something like
`'https?://.+:\d+'`, not `'(https?://.):(\d)'`) is greedy and it will
match across the urls from the first `http:` in the line until the last
`:8080` at the end. The regex is incorrect and do not consider to add
newlines to the result.

Then would you please try the following:

```
import re

with open("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.txt") as f:
    Lines = f.readlines()
file_to_write = open("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\output.txt", "w")
pattern = 'https?://(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:</\w+>|/?>))'
for line in Lines:
   m = re.findall(pattern, line)
   print('\n'.join(m))
   file_to_write.write('\n'.join(m) + '\n')
file_to_write.close()
```